# Java Spring MVC - RequestMapping method won't invoke

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code for a method thats supposed to return a file for download. The path variables are used to navigate to a specific file on the filesystem.

```
@GetMapping("/files/{username}/{docId}/{revisionNo}/{filename:.}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile (@PathVariable("username") String username,
                                           @PathVariable("docId") String docId,
                                           @PathVariable("revisionNo") String revisionNo,
                                           @PathVariable("filename") String filename)
{
    System.out.println("Serve file firing"); // for debug
    String filepath = username + "/" + docId + "/" + revisionNo + "/" + filename;
    Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filepath); // this method works fine
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFilename()+"\"")
            .body(file);
}
```

However when I start the server and go to  "http://localhost:8080/files/admin/0/0/Capture1.PNG" I get a 404 error and no download. The debug println on line 9 doesn't print which would indicate this method is not being triggered.

For context this similar code does work correctly although it doesn't use the filesystem hierarchy i need and only returns files in the root folder.

```
@GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
    Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFilename()+"\"")
            .body(file);
}
```

I think then it must be to do with how I've used the path variables but all the research I've done indicates that its correct...running out of time to fix please help!

Comment: you forgot {filename:.} "+" char ?

Comment: dear lord you're absolutely right, thank you! Sorry to waste your time, so obvious but I'm very tired. Thanks again

Comment: you are welcome